# PHP fatal error when trying to use function from another php file

Tags: php

I have looked through some of the other questions on here about including variables from another php file but I've had no luck.

I am trying to include the return of a function in my `<title></title>`

```
randomtitle.php

function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
```

Here is my index.php

```
index.php

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <?php require_once('randomtitle.php'); ?>
    <title><?php echo generateRandomString(); ?></title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I get a fatal error `Call to undefined function generateRandomString()`. Also the actual randomtitle.php file gets displayed in the body of my index.php.

Comment: Code works fine for me! Do you include this file also into another file? Also add like a: `echo "here";`in your randomtitle file to check that it is actually included

Comment: are you sure both files are on the same directory?

Comment: You code is working for me.. Are they in same directory?

Comment: Try using include_once instead of require

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com ... functionally that'll make naff all difference; and arguably that file *should* be required since the script will fail if it's not there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your randomtitle file is missing the `<?php ... ?>` tags. Without that, PHP will NEVER execute the code within, and treat everything as plain output.

Remember that there is no such thing as a "php script". There are only files with `<?php ... ?>` code blocks within.

Comment: I automatically assume that he has php tags in his file, but if that is the error,  I really have to laugh :)

Comment: look at op's last line: `Also the actual randomtitle.php file gets displayed in the body of my index.php.`

Comment: ^ lel totally missed that! And now I really have to laugh ;) (Now we have this for other dupe questions if we didn't already have one for this error)

Comment: @Mr.Smithyyy: No worries. It's monday. I'm still waiting for my inevitable monday-morning screwup to occur.

Answer (score 1):

Did you have `<?php ?>` in your randomtitle.php file ?

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: I know you can't comment, but you shouldn't answer like this.

Comment: I know this should be a comment but it doesn't really deserve that downvote... if it was changed from a question to a statement it would, quite probably, be the correct answer...

Comment: This is essentially the same answer as the accepted one. Don't it deserves downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the problem is one of these:

- You're missing the PHP opening tag in randomtitle.php
- There's a typo (which I couldn't find)
- The route for the require_once is wrong

Comment: *My guess* Don't do guess work as answers! Use comments for clarification.

Comment: That doesn't mean you should post such answers. You will be able to comment if you have enough reputation.